# Adding Invitees to event programmatically

Tags: event, python

I have a Google Event with a list of invitees. I have a python code which syncs this event with Salesforce by creating a Event sObject. I queried for the emails in the invitees list of my Google event to check whether such a contact exists.

Now I want to add Invitees through my python code to the Event sObject created in sync with Google Event.Is it possible to add Invitees(who are Contacts) to Event sObject programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explore Event Relationship object of salesforce .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm

You can create an Event relationship in salesforce and attach the contact Id if it exists in sfdc

```
EventRelation er = new EventRelation(EventId = '00UD0000005zijH', 
RelationId = '003D000000Q8aeV', isParent = true, isInvitee = false);
insert er;
```

> RelationId is a contact, lead, user, or calendar